# Lowercase and append a text from ressources in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, controltemplate, lowercase

I want to use Label or TextBlock that will display a lower cased and appended with ":" character string that I get from resources. 
For example something like this:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static Localization:Captions.Login}" />
```

where Captions.Login is the string "Login", and the output in my view should be: "login:".
I added a template for Label, that appends ":", but I cannot get to lowercase my string within this template:

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="LabelControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            <Run Text=":"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

The same I can get by using without the Controltemplate, the line of xaml:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static Localization:Captions.Login}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:" />
```

So to end, my question is how to bring lowercase functionality in this scenario(note I do not want to use TextBox and restylings to achieve this)

Answer (score 0):

what about using binding and a converter?

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source="{x:Static Localization:Captions.Login}", Path=., Converter="{StaticResource MyToLowerWithDotConverter}"/>
```

something like that? i have no IDE atm so i dont know if the bindings are right.

Comment: I'm interested in the scenario described above, is there a way to accomplish it?

Comment: binding is not my case in this scenario

Comment: with my solution you have to use binding because you wanna use a converter to achieve your lowercase with ".". just take the converter Cole posted and my xaml and try it out

Comment: sorry, think it's my fault, I wasn't quite explicit: I have already done this implementation with binding and I stored this in styles; the question is that we may have or not another approach of doing this without using binding+converter, that in my opinion would be a cleaner and more natural way, but googling didn't helped me in answering this question.

Comment: when doing mvvm you can add a property which to the converter stuff, but all in all, i would say the converter+binding is a nice easy and clean way

Answer (score 0):

Use a Converter to transform your string to lowercase.

```
public class LowerCaseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((string)value).ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // unnecessary
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```